# How to use Two TileMap in a libgdx game

Tags: dictionary, libgdx, tile

I have a very huge TileMap in my game so i divided it into two different Tile Maps but now i don't know how to use it in game.I mean Loading,merging both the Tile maps,Unloading,rendering etc

Comment: It depends. Are those two tilemaps laid next to each other, or are they laid on top of each other?

Comment: It should be next to each other as per the game..

Comment: Then you need to know when u reach the end of the first map (border of first map where next map starts) and then as soon as the player is out of bounds of the current map, load the new map.